# Fail on focusing First child of an ItemsControls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an ItemsControl that automatically hides itself when the ItemSource is null, and that should focus the first child after showing it self.
I achieved the correct triggering by simple adding the following handler to the "IsVisibleChanged" event:

```
if ((bool)e.NewValue)
{
    ItemsControl control = sender as ItemsControl;
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.UpdateLayout();
        Task task = Task.Run(delegate ()
            {
                while (control.Items.Count == 0 || 
                       control.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.NotStarted ||
                       control.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.GeneratingContainers) ;
            });

        if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(1000)) == task)
        {
            ContentPresenter first = control.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ContentPresenter;
            if (first != null) (first.ContentTemplate.FindName("textBox", first) as System.Windows.UIElement).Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

The handler always works perfectly in the first time that the ItemsControls is show, but the last line throws a InvalidOperationException when calling by the second time.

The handler works works by waiting the ItemContainerGenerator finish its job (or a timeout of one second), then it gets the ItemsControl's first container and from the container it focus the element named "textBox".

I would be glad if any one can tell me what is wrong, because the only thing falling to execute is the `if (first != null) (first.ContentTemplate.FindName("textBox", first) as System.Windows.UIElement).Focus();` line.

Exception Message: 
This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied.

StackTrace: 
at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.FindName(String name, FrameworkElement templatedParent)
at ***.d__1.MoveNext() ...

Comment: what is the stack trace and the message of the exception being raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to work myself, it seams that the problem was that the container wasn't been fully initialized, so i replaced the last line to check the "IsLoaded" property and perform some extra work and also corrected the waiting task.

```
if ((bool)e.NewValue)
{
    ItemsControl control = sender as ItemsControl;
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.UpdateLayout();
        Task task = Task.Run(delegate ()
                    {
                        while (control.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.NotStarted ||
                               control.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.GeneratingContainers) ;
                    });

        if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(1000)) == task)
        {
            ContentPresenter first = control.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ContentPresenter;
            if (first != null)
            {
                if (first.IsLoaded)
                {
                    (first.ContentTemplate.FindName("textBox", first) as System.Windows.UIElement).Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    RoutedEventHandler onload = null;
                    onload = delegate
                    {
                        first.Loaded -= onload;
                        (first.ContentTemplate.FindName("textBox", first) as System.Windows.UIElement).Focus();
                    };
                    first.Loaded += onload;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```